# Converting 8 bytes (c# datetime ticks) to javascript datetime

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, double

I have a server service that moniters and keeps a bunch of c# client apps updated. some of my packets have dates being sent to the clients. The latest attempt to make some of the clients better (as they all have web browsers that can use websockets. However the c# code has issues sometimes) I figure i could just send the same packets to javascript and parse out what i need.

I would prefer not to change the existing packet and to not create another byte[] with different data to send to the web. Is there anyway to extract the date time from those 8 bytes?

The obvious issue is there is no true long in javascript.
Therefore the c# way of reconstructing the long will not work

```
; javascript code to convert 8 bytes into a long
; shifting the number over 32 bits doesnt work as it goes into javascripts special place.
var num = ((arr[0 + offset] | (arr[1 + offset] << 8)) | (arr[2 + offset] << 0x10)) | (arr[3 + offset] << 0x18);
var num2 = ((arr[4 + offset] | (arr[5 + offset] << 8)) | (arr[6 + offset] << 0x10)) | (arr[7 + offset] << 0x18);
return num | (num2 << 0x20);
```

Is there a way to convert the long to javascript datetime?

```
; C # code

; Time | 3/28/2018 5:40:07 PM
; actual bytes = [28, 107, 42, 75, 215, 148, 213, 8]
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

; go through web socket to javascript 

var received_Uint8Array = socket.receive();
; how to create date from 8 bytes
```

Comment: And I thought that ISO DateTime formats existed for this kind of interoperability... Seriously, what made you think this was the easiest/fastest solution? Any JSON formatter knows how to serialize into JavaScript--valid format

Comment: well going from c# to c# apps it works out just fine. I also didnt think this would be easy or fast. I was hoping for something ludicrous and clever. The application was never developed for other environments. Im guessing ill need to spend the to time to send separate bytes to the web-socket.

Comment: If you decided to represent your date as a single number - you could have at least chosen some more reasonable number than `Ticks`, such as unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BitConverter again

```
var ticks = BitConverter.ToInt64(received_Uint8Array);
var dateTime = new DateTime(ticks);
```

But as **Camilo Terevinto** mentioned C# has wide system for serealization